# Using Emacs' query-replace-regexp to escape " character

Tags: regex, emacs, replace

I have hundreds of string that take the form

`""Foo, Baz" <foobaz>@fizz.com>"`

I'm trying to use `Query-replace-regexp` to replace those strings with

`"""Foo, Baz"" <foobaz@fizz.com>"`

So far I have a pattern `"\"\"[A-Z]+, [A-Z]+\""` but this doesn't match anything. I can't do a simple find/replace on `""` or `"` because it will cause too many false hits. What the heck am I missing, how can crate a regex that matches my prescribed pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The match is failing because you've put uppercase letters in your search string. From http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Search-Case.html:

> Searches in Emacs normally ignore the case of the text they are
>   searching through, if you specify the text in lower case. Thus, if you
>   specify searching for ‘foo’, then ‘Foo’ and ‘foo’ also match. Regexps,
>   and in particular character sets, behave likewise: ‘[ab]’ matches ‘a’
>   or ‘A’ or ‘b’ or ‘B’.
>
> An upper-case letter anywhere in the incremental search string makes
>   the search case-sensitive. Thus, searching for ‘Foo’ does not find
>   ‘foo’ or ‘FOO’. This applies to regular expression search as well as
>   to string search. The effect ceases if you delete the upper-case
>   letter from the search string.

Assuming the variable [case-fold-search](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CaseFoldSearch) is set to `t` (the default), then if you use this search text:

```
""[a-z]+, [a-z]+"
```

and this replacement text:

```
"\&"
```

Then `query-replace-regexp` will convert this:

```
""Foo, Baz" <foobaz>@fizz.com>"
```

to this:

```
"""Foo, Baz"" <foobaz>@fizz.com>"
```